# Load single channel 16-bit image to a texture in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, orbbec

I am working with a depth sensor (Orbbec Astra Pro) and want to display the infrared image in Unity. The data I receive is an `ushort[]` (or any other type, which is larger than 8bit).
So I can create a single channel 16-bit texture `infraredTexture = new Texture2D(infraredFrame.Width, infraredFrame.Height, TextureFormat.R16, false);`, but I do not know how to fill the texture with the infrared data, as `LoadRawTextureData` only takes a `byte[]` or `IntPtr`.

So in the end I would like to see a 16-bit grayscale texture in Unity. Is this even possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In general note from [`TextureFormat.R16`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.R16.html)

> Currently, this texture format is only useful for runtime or native code plugins as there is no support for texture importing for this format.
>
> Note that not all graphics cards support all texture formats, use SystemInfo.SupportsTextureFormat to check.

I don't have a direct solution for if you actually want to use a [`R16`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.R16.html) format texture except somehow serialize the data to `byte[]` e.g. using [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy) - *NOTE: No idea of this would work at all!*

```c#
ushort[] yourData = // wherever you get this from;
byte[] byteData = new byte[sizeof(ushort) * yourData.Length];

// On memory level copy the bytes from yourData into byteData
Buffer.BlockCopy(yourData, 0, byteData, 0, byteData.Length);

infraredTexture = new Texture2D(infraredFrame.Width, infraredFrame.Height, TextureFormat.R16, false);
infraredTexture.LoadRawTextureData(byteData);
infraredTexture.Apply();
```

Again no clue if it works that way.

---

However, I think you could simply "fake" it in Unity. If it is only for displaying the texture anyway you could rather use a "normal" [`RGB24`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.RGB24.html) texture and simply map your 16-bit single channel data into a grey scale 24-bit RGB color and then apply it using [`Texture2D.SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) like e.g.

```c#
ushort[] yourData = // wherever you get this from;
var pixels = new Color[yourData.Length];

for(var i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
{
    // Map the 16-bit ushort value (0 to 65535) into a normal 8-bit float value (0 to 1)
    var scale = (float)yourData[i] / ushort.MaxValue;
    // Then simply use that scale value for all three channels R,G and B
    // => grey scaled pixel colors
    var pixel = new Color(scale, scale, scale);
    pixels[i] = pixel;
}

infraredTexture = new Texture2D(infraredFrame.Width, infraredFrame.Height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

// Then rather use SetPixels to apply all these pixel colors to your texture
infraredTexture.SetPixels(pixels);
infraredTexture.Apply();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :) I will test them later.

Comment: I tried the Buffer.BlockCopy example above with signed short 16bit data but returned wrong texture colored in red - GetPixels() showed red got populated bga were 1. @derHugo In the second example, is ushort.MaxValue the max range (i.e. 65535) of ushort or the max ushort value found for the data?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano it's quite a while since I wrote this but I think It would be the value that in your data means full white